# Android Picture Databases ImageColumns.DATA is null on HTC D816T Device

Tags: android, android-image, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

This just happened to me on an HTC D816T device, but other devices are running normally.

```
public static String getRealFilePath( final Context context, final Uri uri ) {

    if ( null == uri ) return null;

    final String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    String data = null;

    if ( scheme == null )
        data = uri.getPath();
    else if ( ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals( scheme ) ) {
        data = uri.getPath();
    } else if ( ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals( scheme ) ) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query( uri, new String[] { ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null );
        if ( null != cursor ) {
            if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
                int index = cursor.getColumnIndex( ImageColumns.DATA );
                //here is normal ，index is 0
                if ( index > -1 ) {
                    /*here is unNormal， data is null 
                     This only happened in HTC D816T devices ,other mobiles is normal;*/
                    data = cursor.getString( index );
                }
            }

            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

The Android picture database `ImageColumns.DATA` is `null` and I don't know why. Can someone help me?

Comment: also happens on Nexus 6 devices, if you look at the source and documentation for api 22, you'll see that it's not existing